# Line Integral Over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a smooth curve and $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $Im(\gamma)\subseteq D$
>
> $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$

Why do both $f(\gamma(t))$ and $\gamma'(t)$ are complex numbers?

Comment: $f$ is a complex-valued function, so its derivative is as well. LIkewise with $\gamma$.

Comment: @MPW yes, but also $\gamma(t)$ therefore $\gamma'(t)$ is complex too, thanks

Comment: $\gamma(t)$ denotes a curve in the complex plane, i.e. $\gamma(t) = x(t) + i y(t)$ where $x,y$ are real. $\gamma(t)$ is only real if this curve lies on the real axis.

Comment: Is the above is a theorem or the definition of line integral?